# Ajax not showing Loading image some times...

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, get

Here is my code below,

```
 function image_effect(){
        $.ajax({
      url: "image/image.php",
      global: false, 
      type: "POST", 
      data: ({my_color:encodeURIComponent($('#my_color').val()),my_size:$('#my_size').val(),g_color1:encodeURIComponent($('#g_color1').val()),format:$('#format').val()}), 
      cache: false,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('.mypreviewArea').html("<img src='images/animated_loading.gif' />");
      },
      success: function(html) {
        $('.mypreviewArea').html(html);
      }
    });

        }

$("#my_size").bind("slider:changed", function (event, data) {
  // The currently selected value of the slider


    image_effect();


    });
```

Iam trying to generate new image through IM by passing parameters to server page through ajax, this code works fine by displaying `loading image` before fetching the `actual image` generated from server page... but some times if the generated time is long... `loading image` will be displayed only for short duration and it disappears, after waiting for minutes `the actual out put image will be shown` ...But i want to display `loading image` till the actual image is shown... there should not be a blank space shown, because people will think that ,Page has stopped loading... how to fix this...?

Comment: try complete instead of success in ajax

Comment: compress your `animated_loading.gif` file, or use base64 encoded image so that i will become light weighted and will load fast

Comment: @Koushik complete is not outputing image at all :(

Answer (score 0):

**Try this function work fine:**

```
<div id="loader"> <img id="img-spinner" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" style="position:fixed;left:50%;top:50%;margin-left:-32px;margin-top:-32px;z-index:9999;"/></div>



 $(document).ready(function(){  
        $("#loader").ajaxStart(function() {
         $("#loader").show();
         }).ajaxStop(function() {
           $("#loader").hide();
   });});
```

Comment: Thanks for your repsonse ..but how do we call this ?? do we have to put it inside function then call it in `success`?

Comment: when ajax can  load at that time it's automatically start and when ajax is stop at that time it also stop.try this very simple.

Comment: Iam calling ajax inside the function image_effect() ,i tried using your code inside the function and outside the function,, but did not work :(

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){   $("#loader").ajaxStart(function() {
         $("#loader").show();
         }).ajaxStop(function() {
           $("#loader").hide();
     });});

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're only loading a snippet of HTML which you dump into the page, replacing the loading, and that snippet actually contains the  that loads your real image? In this case, the browser never even *begins* to load the image until *after* your success callback is done!

What you want is to add the new HTML with image to the container, but hidden by default. Attach a load event handler to the image you insert and, when the image is loaded, then display it.

Comment: thanks for your answer but as u can c iam using slider, when ever we move slider new image will be generated, its continus...

Comment: thanks for your answer ,I did exactly the same.`$('.previewArea').html('<img src=im/images/'+$('#format').val()+'>');` but still its same not working...